# Event unsubscribe

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I need to unsubscribe all delegates subscribed on my event. But I found two ways to do it..

```
class Cls
{
    delegate void doDel();
    static event doDel doE;

    void Uns
    {
    //first
    foreach (doDel item in doE.GetInvocationList())
    {
        doE -= item;
    }

    //second
       doE = null;
    }
}
```

What difference between? And what way is best and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First approach is quite correct. As [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) states:

> - Use the subtraction assignment operator (-=) to unsubscribe from an event:
>
>   publisher.RaiseCustomEvent -= HandleCustomEvent;
>
> When all subscribers have unsubscribed from an event, the event
> instance in the publisher class is set to null.