# C# delegate, events - how to unsubscribe?

Tags: c#, events, scope, delegates

I've found the following delegate/event example in an online C# book. But what I miss is unsubscribing the MailWatch object when it dies - what will be the correct way to unsubscribe it?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class NewEmailEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public NewEmailEventArgs ( string subject, string message )
    {
        this.subject = subject;
        this.message = message;
    }
    public string Subject { get { return ( subject ); } }
    public string Message { get { return ( message ); } }
    string subject;
    string message;
}
class EmailNotify
{
    public delegate void NewMailEventHandler ( object sender, NewEmailEventArgs e );
    public event NewMailEventHandler OnNewMailHandler;

    protected void OnNewMail ( NewEmailEventArgs e )
    {
        if ( OnNewMailHandler != null )
            OnNewMailHandler( this, e );
    }
    public void NotifyMail ( string subject, string message )
    {
        NewEmailEventArgs e = new NewEmailEventArgs( subject, message );
        OnNewMail( e );
    }
}
class MailWatch
{
    public MailWatch ( EmailNotify emailNotify )
    {
        this.emailNotify = emailNotify;
        emailNotify.OnNewMailHandler += new EmailNotify.NewMailEventHandler( IHaveMail );
    }
    void IHaveMail ( object sender, NewEmailEventArgs e )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "New Mail:", e.Subject, e.Message );
    }
    EmailNotify emailNotify;
}
class Test
{
    public static void Main ()
    {
        EmailNotify emailNotify = new EmailNotify();
        MailWatch mailWatch = new MailWatch( emailNotify );
        emailNotify.NotifyMail( "Hello!", "Welcome to Events!!!" )
    }
}
```

And why does the MailWatch object receive the second NotifyMail? The MailWatch object is already out of scope and I think it should be already in the Byte-Nirvana?

```
class Test
{
    public static void Main ()
    {
        EmailNotify emailNotify = new EmailNotify();
        {
            MailWatch mailWatch = new MailWatch( emailNotify );
            emailNotify.NotifyMail( "1!", "At live." );
        }
        emailNotify.NotifyMail( "2!", "Still alive." );
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried unsubscribing operator `-=` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event unsubscribe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448258/event-unsubscribe)

Comment: Very minor convenience tweak: `emailNotify.OnNewMailHandler += IHaveMail;` - the  meaning is identical; just easier to type and read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to take control over `MailWatch`'s lifetime. The ideal way would be via `IDisposable`, and have it unsubscribe itself when disposed:

```
class MailWatch : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        emailNotify?.OnNewMailHandler -= IHaveMail;
        emailNotify = null;
    }
```

and make sure you `Dispose()` the instance - ideally via `using`:

```
using(MailWatch mailWatch = new MailWatch( emailNotify ))
{
    emailNotify.NotifyMail( "Hello!", "Welcome to Events!!!" )
   // ..
}
emailNotify.NotifyMail( "Oh no", "No-one is listening to me :(" )
```

Note that this is not related to garbage collection - and indeed, it *cannot* be garbage collected if the "thing with the event" is still aware of it via the delegate.

Comment: Good, this solves both problems. The unsubscription and scope problem.

Answer (score 1):

To unsubscribe, change `+=` of the subscription to `-=`:

```
emailNotify.OnNewMailHandler -= EmailNotify.NewMailEventHandler;
```

For more information you can take a look at [How to: Subscribe to and Unsubscribe from Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: I dont't think that works, you would have to save a reference to the eventhandler so you can unsubscribe exactly that one. If you create a new one when unsubscribing nothing changes (remove somethin, that isn't there)
So just
`var handler = new EventHandler(Method);`
`someEvent += handler;`
`/* do stuff */`
`someEvent -= handler;`

Comment: @Stefan You didn't, I did ;)

Comment: This works. Just the scope problem left - does not work if I just put that line of code in the deconstructor.

Comment: It works with `-= new EmailNotify.NewMailEventHandler( IHaveMail )` !

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that Byte-Nirvana means garbage collection - no, it is not there yet, its instance member is used in the event handler, so it's kept alive as long as that handler is subscribed. Only after you unsubscribe the handler from the event, the object can be garbage-collected.

Comment: Yes I mean garbage. Have to get the garbage things... its a little bit different to C and C++... You should get the second checkmark. THX

Answer (score -1):

Event Subscribe += or Unsubscribe -= those only used

```
 emailNotify.OnNewMailHandler += new EmailNotify.NewMailEventHandler( IHaveMail );
```

that is subscribe events,

```
 emailNotify.OnNewMailHandler -= new EmailNotify.NewMailEventHandler( IHaveMail );
```

that is unsubscribe events.

Comment: This will not work as `new EmailNotify.NewMailEventHandler` always creates a new handler. Thus, the unsubscription part will throw.